# Rerouting all request through php with ought using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using `.htaccess` file to send all upcoming request to `index.php` like :

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

now i do not want to use `.htaccess` file in my server so is there any way i can process or send all the incoming request on some file ? or lets say on `index.php` ?

Comment: No. How are you going to instruct to the server to perform an operation before hitting the PHP interpreter without using an `.htaccess` file. Are you going to modify the `httpd.conf`?

Comment: I dont know much about editing htpd.conf .But some MVC frameworks does same na ?  i mean they process all the request through index.php only right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the corresponding configuration options out of the .htaccess file into the apache config file. They work there as well.

Besides that: No.

You can use `index.php/test` and get the latter via $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] if it was activated in apache ([see manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)), but in this variant you have to prefix all URLs with "index.php/".

A way to automatically redirect every request to index.php is not possible.

If you don't want to use either of this options, you would as a minimum have to create a php file at every position, which you want to be able to access, and in this file redirect or include another file. Not nice.

Answer (score 0):

Hardly, without modifying the webserver's options ie. .htaccess, virtual host file, etc.

However, if you have permissions to run the PHP's buit-in webserver, you can use the built-in webserver.

Enter the command :

```
$ php -S localhost:80 router.php
```

And make you router.php file something like this:

```
<?php
// router.php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
return false;    // serve the requested resource as-is.
} else { 
    echo "<p>Welcome to PHP</p>";
}
?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php